# I can't change SCSS to CSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with this slideshow:

https://codepen.io/bcarvalho/pen/gWPvJB

The HTML is:

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <section class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide is-active ">
          <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="title">Slide title 1</div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>Slide description 1</p>
              </div> 
              <a href="#" class="btn">
                <span class="btn-inner">Learn More</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-container"> 
            <img src="https://www.alixbdanthenay.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Indispensable-1.jpg" alt="" class="image" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="title">Slide title 2</div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>Slide description 2</p>
              </div> 
              <a href="#" class="btn">
                <span class="btn-inner">Learn More</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.alixbdanthenay.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Indispensable-4-1.jpg" alt="" class="image" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="title">Slide title 3</div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>Slide description 3</p>
              </div> 
              <a href="#" class="btn">
                <span class="btn-inner">Learn More</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.alixbdanthenay.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/11.jpg" alt="" class="image" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="title">Slide title 4</div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>Slide description 4</p>
              </div> 
              <a href="#" class="btn">
                <span class="btn-inner">Learn More</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-container"> 
            <img src="https://www.alixbdanthenay.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/20mars17-sans-typo.jpg" alt="" class="image" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pagination">
        <div class="item is-active"> 
          <span class="icon">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <span class="icon">2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <span class="icon">3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <span class="icon">4</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrows">
        <div class="arrow prev">
          <span class="svg svg-arrow-left">
            <svg version="1.1" id="svg4-Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="14px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 14 26" enable-background="new 0 0 14 26" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M13,26c-0.256,0-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-12-12c-0.391-0.391-0.391-1.023,0-1.414l12-12c0.391-0.391,1.023-0.391,1.414,0s0.391,1.023,0,1.414L2.414,13l11.293,11.293c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C13.512,25.902,13.256,26,13,26z"/> </svg>
            <span class="alt sr-only"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow next">
          <span class="svg svg-arrow-right">
            <svg version="1.1" id="svg5-Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="14px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 14 26" enable-background="new 0 0 14 26" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M1,0c0.256,0,0.512,0.098,0.707,0.293l12,12c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414l-12,12c-0.391,0.391-1.023,0.391-1.414,0s-0.391-1.023,0-1.414L11.586,13L0.293,1.707c-0.391-0.391-0.391-1.023,0-1.414C0.488,0.098,0.744,0,1,0z"/> </svg>
            <span class="alt sr-only"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </section>
</main>
```

The SCSS code is :

```css
body {
  font: 14px/2 "Open sans",sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent; 
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  font: 12px/1.2 "Oswald", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0.05s;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: height 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease, opacity 0s linear 0.2s;
  }

  &::after {
    transition:border 0.1s linear 0.05s;
  }

  .btn-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: #373737;
    transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;

    &::before {
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: height 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease, opacity 0s linear 0s;
    }

    &::after {
      border-color: #373737;
      transition:border 0.1s linear 0s;
    }
  }
}

.slideshow { 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;

  .slideshow-inner { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .slides { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .slide { 
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;

    &.is-active {
      display: block;
    }

    &.is-loaded{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .caption { 
      padding: 0 100px;
    }

    .image-container { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      z-index: 1;
      background-size: cover;
      image-rendering: optimizeQuality;

      &::before { 
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
    }

    .image {
      width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      height: 100%;
    }

    &-content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .title { 
      margin: 0 auto 15px;
      max-width: 1000px;
      font: 300 50px/1.2 "Oswald", sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 0.35em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .text {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }

    .btn {
      margin: 15px 0 0;
      border-color: #fff;

      &::before {
        background:#fff
      }
    }
  }

  .pagination { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;

    .item { 
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 15px 5px;
      position: relative;
      width: 46px;
      height: 32px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-indent: -999em;
      z-index: 1;

      + .page {
        margin-left: -2px;
      }

      &::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 5px;
        width: 36px;
        height: 2px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        transition: background 0.2s ease;
      }

      &::after {
        width: 0;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: width 0.2s ease;
      }

      &:hover::before,
      &.is-active::before {
        background-color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }

  .arrows {
    .arrow {
      margin: -33px 0 0;padding: 20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;cursor: pointer;z-index: 3;
    }

    .prev {
      left: 30px;

      &:hover .svg {
        left: -10px;
      }
    }

    .next {
      right: 30px;

      &:hover .svg {
        left: 10px;
      }
    }

    .svg {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      width: 14px;
      height: 26px;
      fill: #fff;
      transition: left 0.2s ease;
    }
  }
}
```

The JavaScript code is:

```js
var slideshowDuration = 500;
var slideshow=$('.main-content .slideshow');

function slideshowSwitch(slideshow,index,auto){
  if(slideshow.data('wait')) return;

  var slides = slideshow.find('.slide');
  var pages = slideshow.find('.pagination');
  var activeSlide = slides.filter('.is-active');
  var activeSlideImage = activeSlide.find('.image-container');
  var newSlide = slides.eq(index);
  var newSlideImage = newSlide.find('.image-container');
  var newSlideContent = newSlide.find('.slide-content');
  var newSlideElements=newSlide.find('.caption > *');
  if(newSlide.is(activeSlide))return;

  newSlide.addClass('is-new');
  var timeout=slideshow.data('timeout');
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  slideshow.data('wait',true);
  var transition=slideshow.attr('data-transition');
  if(transition=='fade'){
    newSlide.css({
      display:'block',
      zIndex:2
    });
    newSlideImage.css({
      opacity:0
    });

    TweenMax.to(newSlideImage,1,{
      alpha:1,
      onComplete:function(){
        newSlide.addClass('is-active').removeClass('is-new');
        activeSlide.removeClass('is-active');
        newSlide.css({display:'',zIndex:''});
        newSlideImage.css({opacity:''});
        slideshow.find('.pagination').trigger('check');
        slideshow.data('wait',false);
        if(auto){
          timeout=setTimeout(function(){
            slideshowNext(slideshow,false,true);
          },slideshowDuration);
          slideshow.data('timeout',timeout);}}});
  } else {
    if(newSlide.index()>activeSlide.index()){
      var newSlideRight=0;
      var newSlideLeft='auto';
      var newSlideImageRight=-slideshow.width()/8;
      var newSlideImageLeft='auto';
      var newSlideImageToRight=0;
      var newSlideImageToLeft='auto';
      var newSlideContentLeft='auto';
      var newSlideContentRight=0;
      var activeSlideImageLeft=-slideshow.width()/4;
    } else {
      var newSlideRight='';
      var newSlideLeft=0;
      var newSlideImageRight='auto';
      var newSlideImageLeft=-slideshow.width()/8;
      var newSlideImageToRight='';
      var newSlideImageToLeft=0;
      var newSlideContentLeft=0;
      var newSlideContentRight='auto';
      var activeSlideImageLeft=slideshow.width()/4;
    }

    newSlide.css({
      display:'block',
      width:0,
      right:newSlideRight,
      left:newSlideLeft
      ,zIndex:2
    });

    newSlideImage.css({
      width:slideshow.width(),
      right:newSlideImageRight,
      left:newSlideImageLeft
    });

    newSlideContent.css({
      width:slideshow.width(),
      left:newSlideContentLeft,
      right:newSlideContentRight
    });

    activeSlideImage.css({
      left:0
    });

    TweenMax.set(newSlideElements,{y:20,force3D:true});
    TweenMax.to(activeSlideImage,1,{
      left:activeSlideImageLeft,
      ease:Power3.easeInOut
    });

    TweenMax.to(newSlide,1,{
      width:slideshow.width(),
      ease:Power3.easeInOut
    });

    TweenMax.to(newSlideImage,1,{
      right:newSlideImageToRight,
      left:newSlideImageToLeft,
      ease:Power3.easeInOut
    });

    TweenMax.staggerFromTo(newSlideElements,0.8,{alpha:0,y:60},{alpha:1,y:0,ease:Power3.easeOut,force3D:true,delay:0.6},0.1,function(){
      newSlide.addClass('is-active').removeClass('is-new');
      activeSlide.removeClass('is-active');
      newSlide.css({
        display:'',
        width:'',
        left:'',
        zIndex:''
      });

      newSlideImage.css({
        width:'',
        right:'',
        left:''
      });

      newSlideContent.css({
        width:'',
        left:''
      });

      newSlideElements.css({
        opacity:'',
        transform:''
      });

      activeSlideImage.css({
        left:''
      });

      slideshow.find('.pagination').trigger('check');
      slideshow.data('wait',false);
      if(auto){
        timeout=setTimeout(function(){
          slideshowNext(slideshow,false,true);
        },slideshowDuration);
        slideshow.data('timeout',timeout);
      }
    });
  }
}

function slideshowNext(slideshow,previous,auto){
  var slides=slideshow.find('.slide');
  var activeSlide=slides.filter('.is-active');
  var newSlide=null;
  if(previous){
    newSlide=activeSlide.prev('.slide');
    if(newSlide.length === 0) {
      newSlide=slides.last();
    }
  } else {
    newSlide=activeSlide.next('.slide');
    if(newSlide.length==0)
      newSlide=slides.filter('.slide').first();
  }

  slideshowSwitch(slideshow,newSlide.index(),auto);
}

function homeSlideshowParallax(){
  var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop>windowHeight) return;
  var inner=slideshow.find('.slideshow-inner');
  var newHeight=windowHeight-(scrollTop/2);
  var newTop=scrollTop*0.8;

  inner.css({
    transform:'translateY('+newTop+'px)',height:newHeight
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slide').addClass('is-loaded');

 $('.slideshow .arrows .arrow').on('click',function(){
  slideshowNext($(this).closest('.slideshow'),$(this).hasClass('prev'));
});

 $('.slideshow .pagination .item').on('click',function(){
  slideshowSwitch($(this).closest('.slideshow'),$(this).index());
});

 $('.slideshow .pagination').on('check',function(){
  var slideshow=$(this).closest('.slideshow');
  var pages=$(this).find('.item');
  var index=slideshow.find('.slides .is-active').index();
  pages.removeClass('is-active');
  pages.eq(index).addClass('is-active');
});

/* Lazyloading
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
  var slideshow=$(this);
  var images=slideshow.find('.image').not('.is-loaded');
  images.on('loaded',function(){
    var image=$(this);
    var slide=image.closest('.slide');
    slide.addClass('is-loaded');
  });
*/

var timeout=setTimeout(function(){
  slideshowNext(slideshow,false,true);
},slideshowDuration);

slideshow.data('timeout',timeout);
});

if($('.main-content .slideshow').length > 1) {
  $(window).on('scroll',homeSlideshowParallax);
}
```

I want to copy the files from the web pages to my website.
I changed the SCSS to CSS but it doesn't work. What's the problem?
The code I used to change the SCSS is:

```
sass filename.scss newfilename.css
```

But it looks bad after I change it.

Answer (score 3):

In the CodePen link you posted, try and click the arrow in the top right corner of the CSS panel, and select "View compiled CSS". This will also give you the CSS you need.

Comment: sure it doesn't work , the same problem like if i change it from SCSS to CSS the same code the the same problem ! try to copy it

Answer (score 0):

There already a function to change SCSS on Codepen but if there any chance Codepen Does not work, try other website like JSFiddle,CSS Deck,JS Bin,Dabblet,Plunker,Liveweave.
Credit to https://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

i find the problem , in :

```
https://codepen.io
```

can't the files all be in three windows so i need to download the slideshow from 
the button in right down in right "Export.zip" and download the file and use it !

thanks for all you for staying with me ♥

Comment: That's great! Don't forget to mark this as the answer!